# How to make wireshark show http protocol instead of 802.11?

Tags: macos, http, wireshark

I recorded the wlan traffic in my network and saved this as a pcap file. Now I'd like to see the recorded http traffic and filter for some parts of the http traffic.

I can open the pcap file in wireshark and it shows what you can see in the attached screenshot , but I don't find a way to see ip addresses or http messages. If I filter for http I get an empy list.

How can I make wireshark showing me the captured http traffic?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `http` into the filter box hit `enter`

[image]

Comment: This gives me an empty list.

Comment: Then your capture has no HTTP traffic in it. Eek

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm on a WPA encrypted network. After setting the WPA key in wireshark I started to see http trafic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in http traffic, I would recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) instead of Wireshark. It's not as powerful as Wireshark, but speaking of HTTP traffic, I think it's much easier to use and understand.

Comment: "Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet". I need to analyze everything on my WLAN and I don't have a Windows box at hand.

Comment: Yes - as the brightly colored jellybeans in the window title bar and scrollbar indicate, this is OS X, not Windows.  There's a Web debugging proxy for OS X, named [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com), but if you want to analyze *third-party* traffic (as in "I need to analyze everything on my WLAN), then, as noted, a Web debugging proxy is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, it's encrypted traffic on a "protected" network (WEP or WPA/WPA2), so you need to provide the network password to allow Wireshark to decrypt it and, for WPA/WPA2 networks, such as this network, you also have to make sure you capture the EAPOL handshakes for any devices whose traffic should be decrypted.

See [the Wireshark Wiki page on decrypting 802.11](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) for details.